# Sending login credentials while page navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Scenario**
I have placed a button in one of the pages(let's call it *pageA*) in my app. On clicking the button, I am redirecting it to another page(*pageB*) via a login page(*Lpage*). For the purpose of navigation, I am using javascript's method  `window.location.assign()`.

> *pageA*  ----------------------> *Lpage* (enter credentials) ----------------------> *pageB*

**Problem**
Every time I visit *Lpage*, I have to manually enter the credentials because I need to clear the cookies everytime.

**Required**

1. I want to send the credentials(Username + Password) while calling
   the *pageB* from *pageA*
2. *Lpage* should fetch the credentials, automatically login and
       land to *pageB*.

Would it be possible to achieve this scenario in angularJS or vanilla javascript ?

Comment: angularjs [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) provides stateparams, could this be what you're looking for?

Comment: Don't know if I understood. To clarify: you do have a working authentication system, but - for some reason - you have to delete all your users session cookies everytime?

Comment: You can store the user auth token in the cookies and check if the token is set thereby avoiding the login page. But why do you need to clear cookies?

Comment: @Guillaume Thank you. Yes, it can certainly help me solve the first requirement and to a certain extent, the second one as well. But how can I fix the auto login and navigation to pageB ?

Comment: The only way is to store the auth token in `cookies` and every time a `view/state` is changed, you can check for the token. If present, redirect to desired page. Else, redirect to login page.

Comment: @mrlew Yes, you have understood perfectly. The cookies, to certain degree, become the unknown cause of failure scenarios during flow checks. Just to make sure, it doesn't cause any trouble, I am clearing the cookies before the starting the tests(along with cache and history -- might sound funny :) ). Extra caution.

Comment: @Ayan when navigating to Lpage, if the appropriate stateparams are set to be the credentials, you can login and redirect to page B without the need to manually enter the credentials. if that makes sense..

Comment: @Ayan this is  better than using rootscope. I guess you cold also write a factory that does the same thing

Comment: @Chinni  Thanks for your suggestion. Sorry but is cookies really the 'only' way ? As indicated by our friend Guillaume, we can use $stateparams as well, right ?

To make matters simpler, it would be great, if I could only use JS variables/parameters for this scenario. I would prefer that way.

Comment: @Guillaume It perfectly makes sense. Good one. I'll give this a try. It should solve the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ayan I hope it works!

Comment: @Ayan `$stateParams` will expose your token to the user and will be recorded in the browser history. Also, it will expose the token if the user shares the link with some other person and might lead to security flaws. It is a very bad way IMO to check for auth. `Cookies` or `localStorage` will solve this issue.

Comment: @Chinni cookies and localstorage expose the token too... you need some form of encryption if you want to secure this on the client side

Comment: Yes. They will. Any data in which gets into the browser is exposed . But it won't cause issues when a person share the URL with someone else. Did you understand my point? Let's say if you pass the token in `$stateParams` like `<some_url>?auth=token`, and you use that token to display the logged in user details (through token). Now if the user shares that URL with someone else, that person will be able to see the first user details. Security breach! This is a very bad way of implementing auth. This issue is solved with `cookies` or `localStorage`

Comment: That would be true if stateparams had to be specified in the URL, however they don't have to.

Comment: I am suggesting stateparams as a way to pass data from one state to another. This can also be achieved with a service, with localstorage or cookies, however the question specifically asks not to use localstorage or cookies.

Comment: @Guillaume This has worked and I have used services for this job. The idea of using services struck after I saw your comment about 'factory'. Now I see you mentioning about services as well. Thanks for this fruitful conversation.

Comment: @Ayan I'm glad you fixed your issue. a service is actually the way to go here !

Comment: @Chinni   I must say you have suggested a very promising way of achieving it. but unfortunately, it wasn't the way I wanted it to work. I am very sure I will soon need the utility of cookies or localstorage. Thank you for your time and comments.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered in the comments very aptly by @Guillaume, but I just wanted to post an answer so that the comments don't go unnoticed, as a summary, you can try using services to achieve the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry but you were a bit late. I had already fixed it by then. The good news is I achieved the results exactly by the way you mentioned. So Thank you.